# Django equivalence with datetime

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models

I need that every day the `voted_today` field is reset to `0`.

```
from django.db import models
from datetime import datetime, time

from django.conf import settings
from places.models import Place


class Subscription(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    place = models.ForeignKey(Place, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    last_vote_date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)
    voted_today = models.IntegerField(default=0, editable=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user
```

I think something like this:

```
    def reset_votes_day(user, current_stade):
        subscription = get_object_or_404(Subscription, user=user, place=current_stade.place)
        if (subscription.last_vote_date != today()):
            subscription.voted_today = 0
            subscription.save()
```

But I don't know How can I do this correct:
`subscription.last_vote_date != today()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To compare the dates, you can simply extract date from the `datetime` using the date() function, your code should look like this:

```
today = datetime.today.date()
if subscription.last_vote_date.date() != today:
    subscription.voted_today = 0
    subscription.save()
```

On the suggestion of @schillingt, Above code will work if you're using naive `datetime` objects.

If you're using timezone aware `datetime` objects, change today to this:

```
from django.utils import timezone
today = timezone.now().date()
```

Comment: This answer should mention timezones. It's the bane of every developer's existence, but that doesn't justify us ignoring it.